# Cannot find name 'Many' - Upgrading to TypeScript 3.1.6

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash, typescript3.0

I recently upgraded my Angular project from 6 to 7 and I am facing an issue with the `orderBy` function provided by lodash(v4.7.11).

The error when I am passing a string to `orderBy`'s third parameter is

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type `Many<boolean | "desc" | "asc">`.

My sort variable is named `sort` and I tried declaring a type to it as `sort: Many<boolean | "desc" | "asc">` and then I get the error of

> Cannot find name 'Many'

How do I solve this?

My typescript version is 3.1.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the answers here are facts but it didn't solve it for me. My situation was a little bit tricky.

This is the exact line of code that I am using

`this.actions = _orderBy(this.actions, columnName, (this.sort.dir || this.defaultSort.dir))`

where typescript throws an error during compile time as mentioned above.

Now, I should have mentioned this in the question that I am not directly passing `asc` or `desc` but an expression that evaluates to one of these.

I simply had to do the following to make it work

`[(this.sort.dir || this.defaultSort.dir) === 'asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc']`

**or a better version as Avin suggested**

`(this.sort.dir || this.defaultSort.dir) as ('asc' | 'desc')`

And therefore, making the interpreter understand that either of the values can be the only possible output.

So for anyone, mostly everyone, who is going to be passing a string variable which will have either of the two values can follow this little hack to make things work.

Comment: Can't you restrict the types of `this.sort.dir` and `this.defaultSort.dir` to `'asc' | 'desc'` You can use a type assertion instead of a run-time if condition like so `(this.sort.dir || this.defaultSort.dir) as ('asc' | 'desc')` but restricting the originating types is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

The `Many` type expects an [array of values](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/683aaa657bc827841aff549664f6f9f7b8942eb3/types/lodash/common/collection.d.ts#L1655) as the name suggests. Use `[ "desc" ]`

Edit: On further inspection of the type definitions, `Many` allows for both arrays and single values. `Many<T> = T | ReadOnlyArray<T>`  Working examples:

```
orderBy([ { name: 'john' }, { name: 'kate' }], [ 'name' ],  'asc')
orderBy([ { name: 'john' }, { name: 'kate' }], [ 'name' ],  [ 'asc' ])
```

Comment: I'm getting `Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Many<boolean | "desc" | "asc">'.`

Comment: That's impossible. I've added tested examples. Are you passing a mutable array? It has to be constant.

Comment: It's not a mutable array but the element inside the array, which is a string, is mutable and shows up value only during runtime.

Comment: Same thing xD, you should restrict the type of the string to `'asc' | 'desc'`